# pre_save signal method being called after model's save method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

I'm using pre_save signal for performing some functionality, but when I used print statements to print log, I found that my Model's save method is being called before the pre_save bound method, from what I know pre_save method should be called before, I'm posting my Part of my Code for reference:

Models.py :

```
class RedeemCode(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    reward = models.ForeignKey(Reward, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['code']

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        print("In model save method")
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

in Views.py
my pre_save method:

```
@receiver(pre_save,sender=RedeemCode)
def send_noti(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print("Pre_save Method called ----->",instance)
```

When I add new values from admin panel , and submit it, The model's save method is called First it prints `In model save method` and later pre_save bound method  is called, so the output is like:

```
In model save method
Pre_save Method called
```

From my understanding shouldn't the pre_save bound method be called first and then save method of Model,and output should be like this :

```
Pre_save Method called
In model save method
```

I don't understand what is happening , could anyone please explain why this is happening or If I'm doing something wrong , thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 2):

I found out the reason,the reason this was happening was because, pre_save bound method is called before the `super().save()` method, apparently signals bound with model's save method , not with the one we override so they are executed just before or after model's default save method is called using `super()`, so If I comment `super().save()`
the `pre_save` or `post_save` method is not called.